# Why won't my groups (text and images) align vertically in the middle and horizontally centered regardless of setting the style to do that?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently I'm using Scalable Vector Graphics, which means that I'm using `<g ..>` tags instead of `<div ...>`. What's weird is that the only node I have without a title-group is aligning the text vertically in the middle. When there is a title-group (`<g class="title-group" ...>`) the text won't align. Here's an image of the right one...

[image]

Here is what happens when there is a title-group-

[image]

I'm using JavaScript, CSS, and generating HTML. I've literally specified `vertical-align: middle` everywhere to no avail. Also, I'm having another problem. I want the title-group to be aligned in the middle of the `<g class="body-box" ...>`. Here's a picture of what I want as opposed to what you see earlier.

[image]

Please help. I feel like I've tried everything. If you need to see the code, please ask for what you are looking for in the comments.

Comment: Can you add a simple jsfiddle to fiddle a bit?

Comment: It's not going to be simple but yes I'll do that.

Comment: It's there now.

Comment: It can barely load in js fiddle.

Comment: try the equivalence of text-align:center;

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't with the CSS, it was with the `<g...>` tag. Instead of using style on the g tag I converted the g tag into a `<svg...>` tag and adjusted the x and y parameters which was able to perfectly align the images in the exact spot that I wanted them.